# Special series multiplication

Tags: sequences-and-series

how would you find the value of :

$$
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)
\left(1-\frac{1}{3^2}\right)
\left(1-\frac{1}{4^2}\right)
\ldots
\left(1-\frac{1}{2017^2}\right)$$

Tried looking for some kind of pattern here but in vain .

thanks in advance

Comment: Use a telescope.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For $n \geq 2$, prove that $(1- \frac{1}{4})(1- \frac{1}{9})(1- \frac{1}{16})...(1- \frac{1}{n^2}) = \frac{n+1}{2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663101/for-n-geq-2-prove-that-1-frac141-frac191-frac116). See also [Find the value of x](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992282/find-the-value-of-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(1-\frac{1}{2^2})(1-\frac{1}{3^2})(1-\frac{1}{4^2}).......(1-\frac{1}{2017^2})=$

$(1-\frac{1}{2})(1+\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{3})(1+\frac{1}{3})  .......(1-\frac{1}{2017})(1+\frac{1}{2017})=\frac{1009}{2017}$